# Create a property and its type dynamically using propertydescriptor

Tags: c#, reflection, propertydescriptor

I have a class that will has 2 properties

```
public class PropertyBag
{
    public string PropertyName {get;set;}
    public object PropertyValue {get;set;}
}
```

so this "PropertyValue" property can hold any primitive datatype i.e. int, datetime, string, etc.

I am reading settings from custom configuration file with nested elements. Something like this:

```
<Workspace name="ws1">
  <property name="version" type="decimal"> 1.3 </property>
  <property name="datetime" type="datetime"> 10-10-2015 </property>
  <property name="mainwindowlocation" type="string"> 10 300 850 </property>
  ...more nested elements...
</Workspace>
```

I want to be able to set the type of the "PropertyValue" property dynamically based on the value from the config file. A colleague mentioned about PropertyDescriptors/TypeDescriptors/dynamic. Any suggestions with specific implementation detail ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a switch statement to parse value based on the type value.

```
var properties = XDocument.Load("XMLFile2.xml").Descendants("property").Select(p =>
{
    string name = p.Attribute("name").Value;
    string type = p.Attribute("type").Value;
    string value = p.Value;

    PropertyBag bag = new PropertyBag();
    bag.PropertyName = name;

    switch (type)
    {
        case "decimal":
            bag.PropertyValue = Decimal.Parse(value);
            break;

        case "datetime":
            bag.PropertyValue = DateTime.Parse(value);
            break;

        default:
            bag.PropertyValue = value;
            break;
    }

    return bag;
});
```

Comment: Your solution actually addresses the problem statement so I marked it as a solution however I was still looking for how PropertyDescriptor could address this issue around building property dynamically and how would the user consume these properties (get and set them).